# List files in cmd.exe numerically by default to generate a gif out of a sequence of frames

Tags: command-line, windows-8.1, dir

Greetings and Salutations All,

I'm trying to create an animation using imagemagick via:

```
convert -delay 80 -loop 0 *.png ani.gif
```

The logic is finding all the .png files, except the file names are not listed numerically. This causes the animation sequence to be poorly built.

e.g

```
-a---         3/17/2015   8:36 PM      14147 26.png
-a---         3/17/2015   8:37 PM      13904 260.png
-a---         3/17/2015   8:37 PM      13981 261.png
-a---         3/17/2015   8:37 PM      13863 262.png
-a---         3/17/2015   8:37 PM      14026 263.png
-a---         3/17/2015   8:37 PM      14023 264.png
-a---         3/17/2015   8:37 PM      14038 265.png
-a---         3/17/2015   8:37 PM      13913 266.png
-a---         3/17/2015   8:37 PM      14003 267.png
-a---         3/17/2015   8:37 PM      14000 268.png
-a---         3/17/2015   8:37 PM      13887 269.png
-a---         3/17/2015   8:36 PM      14025 27.png
```

I've tried to force the directory to a list by time & date to no avail via:

```
set dircmd=/o:d
```

How could I get it so that the files would be internally listed as:

```
-a---         3/17/2015   8:36 PM      14147 26.png
-a---         3/17/2015   8:36 PM      14025 27.png
-a---         3/17/2015   8:37 PM      13904 260.png
-a---         3/17/2015   8:37 PM      13981 261.png
-a---         3/17/2015   8:37 PM      13863 262.png
-a---         3/17/2015   8:37 PM      14026 263.png
-a---         3/17/2015   8:37 PM      14023 264.png
-a---         3/17/2015   8:37 PM      14038 265.png
-a---         3/17/2015   8:37 PM      13913 266.png
-a---         3/17/2015   8:37 PM      14003 267.png
-a---         3/17/2015   8:37 PM      14000 268.png
-a---         3/17/2015   8:37 PM      13887 269.png
```

Then when the convert command is run the right sequence would be pressed into a gif?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably your convert program sorts the files alphabetically by name when you use a wildcard. The simplest solution would be to rename the files with zero padding so that the file names sort in the proper numeric order.

I've written a hybrid JScript/batch utility called [JREN.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081) that can use regular expression replacement to rename files. It is pure script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

[JREN.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081) makes the solution extremely simple (assuming, for example, you don't already have an existing 027.png that conflicts with 27.png):

```
jren "^\d+(?=\.png)" "lpad($0,'000')" /j
```

After running the command, a file named 5.png would become 005.png, and 27.png would become 027.png. Your original convert command should then be able to process the files in the correct order.

Use `jren /?` to get full documentation on the many options available to JREN.BAT

---

You can do the rename using pure batch, but it is not nearly as convenient

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%F in (
  'dir /b /a-d ???.png ^| findstr "^[0-9][0-9]*\.png$" /i'
) do (
  set "num=000%%~nF"
  ren "%%F" "!num:~-3!%%~xF"
)
```

Comment: or using PowerShell: `dir *.png | foreach {Move $_.Name $_.Name.PadLeft(10,'0')}`